# How to calculate an event window for FOMC interest change announcement on S&P500 returns

Tags: stata

I'm doing a event study in Stata on the effect of FOMC interest change announcement on S&P500 returns.
I have variables for date and for event days (announcementdays), where the value is 1 every time there is an event.

I have trouble with calculating my event window. The event window needs to range from -2 to 2. So everytime the event value is 1, I need the values in a new variable to be -2,-1, 0 on the event day and 1, 2.

To illustrate, in the new variable row 15 should be 0, observation 14 should -1 and observation 16 should be 1 and so on. This loop needs to go through all the occasions where the event is equal to 1.

[End Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokYR.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to what I typically call the "event time" variable. Here's how to make such a variable on a simple example dataset.

```
input id date event 
1 20 0
1 21 0
1 22 1
1 23 0
2 20 0
2 21 0
2 22 1
2 23 0 
end
```

Check out the comments below:

```
* First make a column with the date whenever there's an event
gen date_with_event = date if event==1 

* Then find the earliest event for each ID
bys id: egen first_date_with_event = min(date_with_event)

* The event time is the current date minus that date
gen event_time = date - first_date_with_event

list
```

The final output is

```
    +----------------------------------------------------+
     | id   date   event   date_w~t   first_~t   event_~e |
     |----------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1     20       0          .         22         -2 |
  2. |  1     21       0          .         22         -1 |
  3. |  1     22       1         22         22          0 |
  4. |  1     23       0          .         22          1 |
  5. |  2     20       0          .         22         -2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------|
  6. |  2     21       0          .         22         -1 |
  7. |  2     22       1         22         22          0 |
  8. |  2     23       0          .         22          1 |
     +----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This works fine for your example. I guess the OP wants 0s outside each window, easily enough fixed with `replace event_time = 0 if abs(event_time) > 3`. Or missings. The question isn't clear on this.

Comment: Hi @braces! Thanks for taking the time to help, much appreciated! Well, you should be onto something, i've been trying to work with some of the same code. Firstly, i need the event window to be -2 to 2 on all of the events. I can see that the second event in your code only contains -1 to 1. Also, I'm not quite sure of the though behind why the first four obs are ID=1 and the fifth being ID=2? At last, like Nick mentioned, all other dates which is not around a event should be 0. Thanks.

Comment: I confess I am a bit confused about your aims here...You can use Nick's code to leave out event_times outside of the -2 to 2 window. To your other questions, the data I provided is a mock example, showing 4 observations of company 1 and 4 observations of company 2. This would be the basic setup for an event study, perhaps you can share what your data looks like if it's still unclear.

Comment: @braces I'm new to this platform, so I'm not sure I'm navigating the right way. But i added an "answer" with two screenshots.

Comment: You have more problems than you express. The image you posted -- still visible at the time of writing in the deleted question to those with enough reputation -- shows that you have gaps at weekends (and perhaps over some other days). This raises the issue of how you want to count across gaps. Simple subtraction will make the gap from Friday to Monday 3 days, for example. Perhaps you should set up a business calendar.